# How to use Guillotine Menu in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I want to use this Navigation Drawer in my app - [GuillotineMenu-Android](https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android)

I have read the description given on the github page but am unable to figure out how to apply it on my app.

Here is my activity_main:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<include layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My toolbar layout is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

My Mainactivity.java is as follows :-

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

 import com.yalantis.guillotine.animation.GuillotineAnimation;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Toolbar toolbar;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.hamburgr_icon);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}
}
```

And the menu that i want to show on the navigation drawer is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
        android:title="first" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
        android:title="second"

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
        android:title="Third" />
</group>


<item
    android:id="@+id/contact_us"
    android:title="Contact Us"/>



</menu>
```

I have already imported the GuillotineMenu-Android library to my android studio but cant figure out how to use it. So it would be of immense help if someone could tell me how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the github repo link you provided is broken

Comment: :( But its working for me. Anyway, here is the link again-  https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you MainActivity with this code :  https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yalantis/guillotine/sample/activity/MainActivity.java

and your layout file with : https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity.xml

and create a guillotine layout file like : https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/guillotine.xml

use